# UIView height based on content with Autolayout

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6, autolayout, ios7

I'm trying to create a section header in a UITableview that contains 3 labels, with a layout that looks a bit like this

```
-------------------------------
| title              | dist   |
|                             |
| Description                 |
|                             |
-------------------------------
```

`Title` and `time` are both fixed size, but the `description` needs to automatically adjust its height based on the content, with a minimum height of a single line of text.

My current header structure consists of

```
UIView
|_ UIView
      |_ UILabel
      |_ UILabel
      |_ UILabel
```

The outer UIView is the section header itself, with a clear background, and the inner UIView is the visible view with the labels.

What I'm after, is for the section header to adjust it's height according to the content that is in the description label.

I've tried implementing the `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` but it doesn't seem to be working. iOS is complaining about having to break constraints which I guess makes sense given I've set constraints, but then manually override them with this method?

How can I create constraints that allow the view to resize itself? Right now, I have the following implementation of `viewForHeaderInSection:`

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        UIView *header = [UIView new];
        UIView *headerBg = [UIView new];
        UILabel *title = [UILabel new];
        UILabel *distance = [UILabel new];
        UILabel *desc = [UILabel new];

        headerBg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        distance.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        desc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [headerBg setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.8]];

        [title setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14.0]];
        [title setTextColor:kFONT_COLOUR];
        NSString *address = _place.address ? (_place.address.length > 0 ? _place.address : @"Unknown Address") : @"Unknown Address";
        [title setText:address];

        [distance setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0]];
        [distance setTextColor:kFONT_COLOUR];
        [distance setText:@"Distance: ?m"];
        [distance setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];

        [desc setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:11.0]];
        [desc setTextColor:kFONT_COLOUR];
        [desc setNumberOfLines:0];
        [desc setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        [desc setText:_place.desc ? (_place.desc.length > 0 ? _place.desc : @"No Description Given") : @"No Description Given"];

        [headerBg addSubview:title];
        [headerBg addSubview:distance];
        [headerBg addSubview:desc];

        NSDictionary *bindings = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(title, distance, desc, headerBg);

        [headerBg addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-9-[title]-[distance(100)]-9-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:bindings]];
        [headerBg addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-9-[desc]-9-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:bindings]];
        [headerBg addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-9-[title(20)]-[desc]-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading metrics:nil views:bindings]];

        [header addSubview:headerBg];
        [header addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[headerBg]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:bindings]];
        [header addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[headerBg]-9-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:bindings]];
        return header;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Any help would be great :)

Comment: Nope :( Still nothing. I was able to do without it temporarily but that was just to demo the app so I didn't have enough content to break it. But still looking for a fix ideally